When the Browser navigation button for previous page clicked router change is not reflected in Node js
When the Browser navigation button for previous page clicked router change is not reflected in Node js Application .because of proper management of session or cache
In your app.js file you have to require nocache library
var no_cache = require('nocache');
and then add middleware corresponding to it:
app.use(no_cache());

And your question is?
